# How can i store the data of a text field with out using a submitting button in php

Tags: php, javascript

How can I store the data of a text field in mysql without using a submit button in php.I am using wamp server.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Who imposed this constraint, "*without using a submit button*"? Is this a hateful job interview question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store the data without clicking a submit button, you can use the JavaScript. Then,  you require an automated submission.

The example of javascript to submit the form, let's name the form as *"myform"*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanx it works, is it possible to submit the form in a particular time duration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ajax submission by handling the onchange event of your textbox. Have a look at jQuery, if you don't know what that is, read a tutorial (there are thousands on line).

Basically what you need to do is capture the onChange event of your text field so that when the user changes the field, your onchange can send a json datum packet back to a php script on your server that can update the appropriate field.

Comment: any reason to use a "json data packet" and not just a POST or GET request with normal fields?

Comment: @DougM it could be anything in reality, (of course a json data packet would also be either POST'd or GET'd or PUT'd or whatever). I just mentioned  json so that OP can google it  and learn about it too. just-in-cases :P

Answer (score 0):

you can submit form using onChange or keypress Events..Keypress would be better

here is the sample jQuery Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('#yourformid').each(function() {
        $('input').keypress(function(e) {
            // Enter pressed?
            if(e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
                this.form.submit();
            }
        });

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: I use setInterval function, I think it will be simple.

Comment: setInterval  ..its not good idea..how you can be sure ..user has entered data or not

Comment: I use onload function in the body and with javascript the input will find.

Comment: there are chances like form will get submitted while user typing in the textbox

Comment: It will work only for the system input like date,time, client machine name....